# How to terminate a R function by return-like keyword or return different values based on different conditions?

Tags: r, return-value

I'm a new learner to R. Now I have two similar questions for R.

1. How to terminate a R function in an if condition, just like the `return` in language as `c` and `python`?
2. How to return different values based on different conditions in R?

e.g. how to implement `c= a>b?a:b` in R, just like the structure of C code below.

```c
int max(int a, int b){
    if(a>b)
        return a
    else
        return b
}
```

Comment: R's "return-like" keyword is `return()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `R` version of your example could be written like this:

```
findmax <- function(a, b){
  if(a > b)
    return (a)
  else
    return (b)
}
```

Or, the same code in a shorter form:

```
findmax <- function(a, b){ifelse(a > b, a, b)}
#> findmax(4, 3)
#[1] 4
```

The `R` function `ifelse(a>b, a, b)` is analogous to `a>b?a:b` in `C`.

Hope this helps.